# Date time picker control

Tags: java, layout, datepicker, swt

I look for date time picker control which look like this:[image]
<sub>(source: [functionx.com](http://www.functionx.com/visualstudio/forms/datepicker2.gif))</sub>

All controls which I found don't use system layout.
It would be great if this control use system style and layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you already look at these?

http://swtcalendar.sourceforge.net/demos.html

http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/calendarcombo/calendarcombo.php

Answer (score 2):

SWT has a widget called `DateTime` which looks similar to the one in your image.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/CreateaDateTimecalendarandaDateTimetime.htm